# Why are the arguments to BGL functions separated by dots, instead of commas?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am reading someone's codes. This is a function from boost graph library. 
This is the original function definition.

```
 void dijkstra_shortest_paths
      (const Graph& g,
       typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor s, 
       PredecessorMap predecessor, DistanceMap distance, WeightMap weight, 
       VertexIndexMap index_map,
       CompareFunction compare, CombineFunction combine, DistInf inf, DistZero zero,
       DijkstraVisitor vis, ColorMap color = default)
```

This is the piece of code I picked out from someone's. It works, but I just don't understand why he used dot in between `predecessor_map weight_map`and`distance_map` instead of comma? How many parameters he passed into the function?

```
dijkstra_shortest_paths(graph, source_vertex,
                          predecessor_map(&predecessors[0])
                          .weight_map(get(&Edge::cost, graph))
                          .distance_map(&distances[0]));
```

Comment: Huh?? Dot and comma operators are orthogonal features? What you're actually asking about?

Comment: I am confused the dot in predecessor_map(&predecessors[0])
                          .weight_map(get(&Edge::cost, graph))
                          .distance_map(&distances[0])    I think it should be a comma to separate different parameters. using '.' means it is a class and then member and then a member under that member

Comment: The question would be better worded as "I don't know what is goind on here. It looks like arguments are being passed separated with a `.` instead of a `,`". Open questions are **much less confusing**. Your misunderstanding prevents people from seeing the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/bgl_named_params.html) explains what's going on:

> Many of the Boost.Graph algorithms have a long list of parameters,
>   most of which have default values. This causes several problems.
>
> [...]
>
> A better solution is provided by `bgl_named_params`. This class allows
>   users to provide parameters is any order, and matches arguments to
>   parameters based on parameter names.
>
> [...]
>
> Each
>   of the arguments is passed to a function whose name indicates which
>   parameter the argument is for. Each of the named parameters **is
>   separated by a period, not a comma**.
>
> [...]
>
> Typically the user **never needs to deal with the `bgl_named_params` class
>   directly, since there are functions like `boost::weight_map`** that create
>   an instance of `bgl_named_params`.

See also [What is the “Named Parameter Idiom”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom).